# Is there any way to detect if current tab URL hash is changed - Chrome Extension Development

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension, Some of my function works when the page reloads, but in some website content is changed without reloading the page, only hash is changed. My functions are in content script. I need to reload them as URL changes.

I tried to use `window.location.hash`, I wrote this line in content script, but I see no result.
I am not sure is it because of content script or something else.

It would be very helpful if anyone tell me any way to reload my functions when URL changes. Thank you very much. Very much appreciate your help.

Comment: Use `hashchange` and `popstate` events, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39508954).

Comment: @wOxxOm You're life savior! thank you so much. Really appreciate your help.